# When does Stream.Read returns?

Tags: c#, stream, .net

Consider this simple code:

```
    public void TransferStream(Stream source, Stream target)
    {
        Int32 read = -1;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[4096];
        do
        {
            read = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            target.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        while (read != 0);
    }
```

Imagine that `source` is a `NetworkStream`, and the information is arriving little by little. 
`source.Read` can return with a full buffer, or with a partial one, the `read` will tell how much was read.

When does `source.Read` return if there are no enough data to fill the buffer? When it is enough to return with a partial buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation for `Stream.Read()'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> Implementations of this method read a maximum of count bytes from the
>   current stream and store them in buffer beginning at offset. The
>   current position within the stream is advanced by the number of bytes
>   read; however, if an exception occurs, the current position within the
>   stream remains unchanged.
>
> Implementations return the number of bytes
>   read. **The implementation will block until at least one byte of data
>   can be read**, in the event that no data is available. Read returns 0
>   only when there is no more data in the stream and no more is expected
>   (such as a closed socket or end of file). An implementation is free to
>   return fewer bytes than requested even if the end of the stream has
>   not been reached.

So according to that, the NetworkStream *should* block until either it is closed or until at least one byte is available. Whether it actually does or not is a different matter - but I would hope it does.

It can *definitely* return a partial buffer.

However more generally, I did discover in the past that if you have a file opened in shared mode, and something else is writing to that file while you are reading from it then the `File.Read()` can return zero even though data is still being written to it (and a subsequent read returned non-zero) - so watch out for that kind of thing. I think `NetworkStream` won't suffer from that problem though. Nevertheless, it might be a good idea to write a test program to determine that for sure!

[EDIT]

I looked at the source code for it, and ultimately it ends up calling the Windows API `recv()` function. I know that can return partial buffers, so we must assume that `NetworkStream.Read()` can also return partial buffers.

Comment: Right, I read that but I thought it would be very unlikely that it returns `Byte` by `Byte` if it is a slow connection. But maybe that is how it really works.

Comment: @vtortola I guess you have to look at the source code or test it, to be sure.

Comment: I just took a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx but could not find anything about it.